# Can front-end to do something when 500 internal server come because a lot of access in the same time

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I know maybe this is a strange things to ask but I'm quite curious about this,

***"Is there any way for front-end especially in angular to help when 500 internal server error appear because a lot of access in the same time?".***

this is new for me when build a website that have a lot of traffic in the specific time such as **when an assignment deadline come so a lot of user access it in the same time.**

because I want to help my friend who dealt with the server so maybe there is something I can do with front-end especially when I use angular 7. I mean except change the server because we already tried to upgrade it 2 times

Comment: Is the traffic generated from one user or multiple users? If it's from a lot of users, front-end (Angular) can't solve your problem and it should be fixed by allowing more connections to your server.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error can be anything,..

Comment: front-end can try some "best effort" remediations, such as retrying failed requests after a reasonable delay

Comment: multiple users, from we know more than 1000 - 2000 student access it in the same time

Comment: with `rxjs` you can use `retry(x)` where `x` is how many time you will retry the request. You can do that for a specific error code, for example.

Comment: use cache to reduce traffic to the server if necessary `https://www.npmjs.com/package/a4-observable-cache`

Comment: @flo yeah I think i must try using retry or retryWhen when i search about it to and make sure to limit it so at least it can help to wait until the server up again

Comment: @BillCheng Thanks for your reference I'll try it because this observable cache is new for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the front end I think the first thing you need to do when you're seeing 429 (too many requests) or 5xx (internal errors) is to limit your retry rate. Since if the server fault is due to flooding, that's the best way you can help.

From a UX perspective, there are other things you can do, such as serving local data (taking the progressive web app approach). PWAs are a topic on their own, though.

Comment: Yeah i think this is the only way i can do to help with this problem, I'll try to limit the retry rate first, and for PWA approach do you mean without using routing?

Comment: By PWA I mean using a service worker as a middle ware to handle HTTP requests. If the connection is down somehow, for example you have a WiFi outage or a server error, the service worker can decide to return something from the local storage instead of actually fetching the server data. However PWA is a major feature upgrade, intended to enable your application to continue running offline, not a quick fix to get around a server error. So I doubt you want to do that.  https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker